# N-dimensional Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution

Tags: statistics, physics

I was trying to do an n-dimensional Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution for velocity, but, I can't figure out what is happening in the following passage:

$$f(v){d}^{n}v = \left( \frac{m}{2\pi kT} \right)^{n/2} e^{-\frac{m |v|^{2}}{2kT}} d^{n}v \ \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \ f(v) dv = {(\operatorname{const})} \ \  e^{-\frac{mv^{2}}{2kT}} \ \ v^{n-1} dv \ \ ,$$

where:

$$ (d^n v) = (dv_{1})(dv_{2}) (...) (dv_{n}) \ \ ,$$

and

$$ v^2 = v_{1}^2 + v_{2}^2 + ... + v_{n}^2 \ \ .$$

Source:
[Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution in n-dimensional space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#In_n-dimensional_space)

I couldn't find it anywhere else to double check...

Comment: Notation is unusual.  What does $d^nv$ mean in this context?

Comment: Would be the same as (d^3(v)) in 3D, but in n dimensions now. In 3D you have (d^3(v)) = (dv_x)(dv_y)(dv_z), so, in N-D, (d^n(v)) = (dv_1)(dv_2) (...) (dv_n)

Comment: My confusion was how does $d^nv$ become $v^{n-1}dv$?  Also if $d^nv$ is defined as described, what is $dv$?

Comment: This is exactly my question: "How does $d^{n} v$ become $v^{n−1} dv$?" Actually, that are other things going on behind the scenes. I think with the answer J.G. gave, I can work it out. And, $dv$ is the infinitesimal of the v variable, we write $d^{n} v$ in the N-D case as a compact notation, just that.

Comment: The notation is confusing in terms of what is $v$.  Is it a vector $(v_1,....,,v_n)$?  In that case What does $dv$ mean, since $d^nv=dv_1...dv_n$

Comment: Yes, $\vec{v} = (v_{1}, ..., v_{n})$, but in here we deal with its magnitude, $v=|\vec{v}|$. I understand the confusion you are refering to, but this is standart notation when dealing with integrals in higer dimensions. So, you should not just think that $d^{n}v$ becames $v^{n−1}dv$, because $d^{n}v$ is just a compact notation and not the thing you will act upon. All that said, $dv$ is the infinitesimal of the magnitude of velocity. And, $v^{2} = v_{1}^{2}+v_{2}^{2}+...+v_{n}^{2}$ is an equation for a hypershape, that gives you the magnitude of $\vec{v}$ (just do the square root).

Comment: It would have been much clearer if $\overrightarrow{v}$ and $|\overrightarrow{v}|$ were used instead of $v$.

Comment: You are right. I made it confusing because english is not my primary  language. For me velocity vector and speed (the magnitude of velocity) are translate as one word, both of them, and I forgot about this when I was writing this question.

Comment: The confusion starts with $f(v)d^nv$ on the left and $f(v)dv$ on the right with different meanings for $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a transition in velocity space from Cartesian coordinates to polar ones, with $v$ the polar radius. The constant absorbs the $\left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{n/2}$, as well as a solid angle factor due to integration over the non-polar angles. You don't need to worry so much about that, because of the spherical symmetry. You do need the constant to calculate the probability in a region of velocity space, but you can get it by normalizing the PDF. This is equivalent to computing the $n$-dimensional unit ball's measure.